# Настраивал 404-ю ошибку сайта. Как создать ".htaccess" файл?

Tags: html, .htaccess

В интернете нашел, что настройка 404-й страницы происходит с помощью .htaccess - файла. Однако, данный файл не имеет названия и его невозможно создать. Как его создать или  что использовать чтоб при появлении 404-й ошибки пользователя перенаправляло на выбранную html-страницу?

Comment: *Однако, данный файл не имеет названия и его невозможно создать* - это вы о каком файле?

Answer (score 3):

Создание идет следующим способом:

1. Открыть текстовый редактор (Блокнот).
2. В меню "Файл" выбрать "Сохранить как".
3. В выпадающем списке "Тип файла" выбрать "Все файлы".
4. Ввести в качестве имени ".htaccess".
5. Нажать на кнопку "Сохранить".

А перенаправление выполняется следующим синтаксисом:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.ваш_сайт.ru/404.html
```

Где `http://www.ваш_сайт.ru/404.html` страница, на которую осуществляется редирект.

Comment: может, там должно быть и имя файла после сайта? :)

Comment: @splash58 Ну, редирект может быть куда угодно, в зависимости от желания разработчика, можно на 404.html, а можно на index.html. Так сказать url - может быть любым

Comment: да я понимаю, а вот из вашего кода этого не следует. там кака раз все не необязательное, а нужного нет

Comment: А если в консоли? =)